# Visual Studio upgrade to 2017 15.5.3 breaks solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi in dotnet core 2.0, from which I reference an old dll (.net 3.5) for the main purpose of data access to a database. Everytime I run the solution I am having

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Everything was working fine before the VS update to version 15.5.3

Comment: One of your project references is broken.  Not sure any “answer” can be provided except to suggest you analyse the projects and dependencies and figure out which reference is broken.  Maybe use dotPeek..?

Comment: Can you put together a project that reproduces this issue? also, which version did it work in before? 15.5.2?

Comment: SQL Server support is natively there in .NET Core 2.0, so why exactly do you need any extra reference?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my webapi (also netcoreappp2.0) and VS2017 15.5.3.

API is using ADO connections with "Systam.Data.SqlClient" provider. What I did is installation Systam.Data.SqlClient package from NuGet (ver. 4.4.2). After this the exception ceased to be thrown.

Comment: Made an Api in net core 2.0, via reflection it uses
an old dll (not mine) that requires system.data.sqlclient.
It stopped working few days ago, now it's working again
installing on the Api via nuget Systam.Data.SqlClient.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using a net standard 2.0 lib inside a project. I finally discovered a bad format error. Made sure the project platform matched in my case x64.